# PHP Autofill or something?

Tags: php, html

I have seen many questions related to auto fill, but none of them worked for me. I'm not even sure if a solution to my problem lies in HTML or PHP. I am new in both of them and I'm still not used to them. I'm working on a simple chat app. What I have now is chat window, text field, and nick name field. Both of them pass the values to the text file (which is how I want this to work, no change here). Problem is that both these fields work as a form, and each time I submit, nick name field refreshes. What I would want is auto completing nickname field so it stays the same (it'd be the best if it stayed even after browser refreshes, but it will be okay if it only goes through the form submit)

code if needed:

PHP:

```
    <?php
    $action = $_GET["action"];
    $myText = $_POST["mytext"];
    $nick = $_POST["nick"];

    if($action = "save") {
        $targetFolder = "/var/www/html/xami/";
        file_put_contents($targetFolder."htmlinput.txt", $nick.">".$myText);
    }?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="?action=save" name="myform" method="post">
    <label for="nick">Nick:</label>
    <input type=text id="nick" name="nick" placeholder="Nick" value="Name" required><br>
    <input type=text name="mytext" placeholder="Text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Send.">
</form>
```

I was fooling around with autocomplete but no positive results.

I'm leaving post for tomorrow, I'll reply then.

Comment: Once the nick is entered, i.e. once `$nick` has a value, why do you need to have it as a form field? If you don't want users to be constantly changing their names you can just remove the nick field in your form once it is known. Then the nick form item could be `type='hidden'`.

Comment: Form will always refresh the page. You may have to call PHP file using AJAX.

Comment: You probably should put it in a session variable, not the form. The user can change hidden form fields using the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is on a .php page you could have...

```
if(0<strlen($nick)){
    echo "<input type=hidden id='nick' name='nick' value='$nick'>";
}else{
    echo "<input type=text id='nick' name='nick' placeholder='Nick' value='Name' required><br>";
}
```

Or, use AJAX as @Rishi says.